# Get summary frequence in a column containing list of values in R

Tags: r, datatable, summary

I have a dataframe such as :

```
                               ANIMALS     query
3                                          A
4                         [CAT], [DOG]     B
5                                          C
6                                [CAT]     D
7                                          E
8                [CAT], [SHARK], [DOG]     F
```

and I would like to get a summary of proportion of numbers list elements between in ANIMALS

**Summary expected :**

```
ANIMALS  Freq
CAT      0.50
DOG      0.33
SHARK    0.17
```

**Here is tha dataframe in dput format if it can helps:**

```
structure(list(ANIMALS = list(character(0), 
    c("[CAT]", "[DOG]"), character(0), "[CAT]", 
    character(0), c("[CAT]", "[SHARK]", "[DOG]"
    )), query = c("A", 
"B", "C", 
"D", "E", 
"F")), row.names = 3:8, class = "data.frame")
```

So far I tried to use the traditional `table(tab$ANIMALS)` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is dplyr and stringr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

unlist(dat$ANIMALS) %>%
 str_extract(., "[A-Z]+" ) %>%
 data.frame(ANIMALS= .) %>%
 group_by(ANIMALS) %>%
 summarise(total = n() ) %>%
 mutate(Freq = total/sum(total))
```

Answer (score 1):

baseR solution

```
animal <- unlist(Filter(length, mydata$ANIMALS))
as.data.frame(table(animal)/length(animal))
#    animal      Freq
# 1   [CAT] 0.5000000
# 2   [DOG] 0.3333333
# 3 [SHARK] 0.1666667
```

Comment: Nice one. Neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% select(ANIMALS) %>% unnest(ANIMALS) %>% 
  mutate(ANIMALS = str_remove_all(ANIMALS, '\\[|\\]'), l = n()) %>% 
    group_by(ANIMALS) %>% summarise(Freq = n()/l) %>% distinct()
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'ANIMALS'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   ANIMALS [3]
  ANIMALS  Freq
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 CAT     0.5  
2 DOG     0.333
3 SHARK   0.167
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(lengths(ANIMALS) > 0) %>% 
   unnest(ANIMALS) %>% 
   count(ANIMALS = str_remove_all(ANIMALS, "\\[|\\]"), name = 'Freq') %>% 
   mutate(Freq = Freq/sum(Freq))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  ANIMALS  Freq
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 CAT     0.5  
2 DOG     0.333
3 SHARK   0.167
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
proportions(table(unlist(df1$ANIMALS)))

    [CAT]     [DOG]   [SHARK] 
0.5000000 0.3333333 0.1666667
```